# How to spin in circle instances of metaballs?

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

[image: loop]

I am working on this loop. Here I have instances of metaballs wiggling location randomly, I duplicated this node tree twice more. Sub-question is how to think about making the random wiggle loop smoother and not so obvious when it restarts.

[image: metaball node tree]

Now, I am wondering how to approach 3 bundles of wiggling metaballs to rotate around the center. Do I work with an empty? How does one take metaball node tree (shown above) and use it as an input to rotate around empty or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

**My approach is to use metaballs as dupliverts**

[image]

This subprogram (bluish) creates user defined amount of pointclouds.

To loop animation I used a couple of identical vector *Wiggle* nodes, but one with subtracted evaluation to make a smooth transition back to initial position.

Another subprogram (green) is mixing every point between pointclouds from both *Wiggl*e nodes.

[image]

This part of a tree controls central point rotation (same trick with looping of two *Wiggle* nodes was used previously) and location (for location I used *Empty*).

First node from left named as *Animation Duration* controls animation length before looping.

*Distribute Matrices* node produces locations for pointclouds. Right now it replicates along the circle, but could be any mesh if needed.

Two *Animate* nodes are mixing start/end positions and use sinusoidal interpolation to give smoother looping.

[image]

Parent *Metaball* to freshly created pointcloud mesh - *Target* and enable duplivert instancing in mesh's object properties. To hide original metaball use shader mask:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for example and solution. I spent some time tinkering cause invoking subprogram is new to me. For the most part I was able to replicate the example, but have a few question.

I couldn't find few nodes and had to copy paste it from your .blend
Vector List Node from AN
Ceil Node from Shader

Comment: Also, I am not sure what I am doing wrong applying Shader to original Metaball, but it doesn't hide like in your file, just stays flat black.

Comment: Unfortunately, some nodes are available only from the search bar. "Vector List Node" was found, when I searched for "vector". As for the shader, I think you might forget to set  alpha mode from opaque to alpha blend inside material tab (Eevee). In Cycles this should work fine though.